# How is `npm publish` different from `yarn publish`?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Is there a difference  between `yarn publish` and `npm publish`? I have written a package, but for some reason, when I publish a new version using `yarn publish` I'm unable to import the package in my other projects. This is confusing because publishing with`npm publish` results in working imports.

```
{
  "name": "@catpic/console-highlighter",
  "version": "0.1.6",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "Highlight console log messages with style.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/dlaub3/highlighter.git"
  },
  "directories": {
    "lib": "./lib"
  },
  "prepublish": "tsc -b",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel --out-dir serve index.html",
    "build": "tsc -b"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.6.1",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "typescript",
    "javascript"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your prepublish script is outside the scripts object, is that right? Have you compared the result of `npm pack` and `yarn pack`?

Comment: That must be it. I'll report back later after testing.

Comment: @404pio that's not the right tag for this Yarn

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok. I'm glad that you corrected it

Comment: This didn't fix the problem. I'll attempt to compare `yarn pack` and `npm pack`.

Comment: The `yarn` package only includes the main file in from the lib folder. It's missing every thing else.

Answer (score 5):

In the end I needed to add the `files` field so that `yarn` would include the full contents of the lib folder.

```
 "files": [
    "lib/**/*"
  ],
```